# Undefined reference to `getaddrinfo_a'

Tags: c, linux, networking

I get linker error while compiling a minimal program that uses `getaddrinfo_a` on Linux. The program in question

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int err;
  err = getaddrinfo_a(0, NULL, 0, NULL);
}
```

Compiler output:

```
 $ cc -lanl minimal.c
/tmp/cc89BuFU.o: In function `main':
minimal.c:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `getaddrinfo_a'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

 $ cc --version
cc (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13) 4.9.2
```

Comment: missing `-lsocket` as i guess....

Comment: I do not have any problem with your code and command. Please find `libanl.so` appropriate for your command and run `nm libanl.so | grep getaddrinfo_a`

Comment: LPs... Please check this link  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo_a.3.html

Comment: @someone Tx for the link

Comment: @Michael  Check my answer. I have given the correct command there. I myself have made that mistake. Difficult to spot unless you have done it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using command in wrong way. Use

```
cc  minimal.c -lanl
```

-lanl should come after not before file name.

```
gcc [options] [source files] [object files] [-Ldir] -llibname [-o outfile]
```

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html

> -l  It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the order they are specified. Thus, ‘foo.o -lz bar.o’ searches library ‘z’ after file foo.o but before bar.o. If bar.o refers to functions in ‘z’, those functions may not be loaded.

According to standard also,  order of library matters. Linker didn't check for symbol from previously specified libraries. [Ref](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/c99.html)

Comment: On my RedHat 7.1 with gcc 4.8.3 it works the way published in the question. The order of things on my system is not important

Comment: @Michael I added reasoning and standard. But you are correct for red hat. But it's not standard behaviour

Comment: I've also thought that `-l` has to be after the objects. But since my RH works another way, I guessed that it might have been the case with Ubuntu, too. GCC and ld should be the same on all Linux distros.In short, I'm surprised.

Answer (score 0):

The library to link must be put after the object (and source files in your case):

```
 $ cc minimal.c  -lanl
```